# Devise encrypted_password is different for the same supplied password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, passwords

I've included a sample script below, but I'm trying to figure out why saving the same password to the same user object is returning a different value for encrypted_password. This is causing massive confusion and passwords not being able to be verified, even through Devise's valid_password? method.

**Sample code:**

```
<% password = 'runbyfruiting'
    user1 = User.new(email: 'foo1@bar.com', password: password)
    user2 =  User.new(email: 'foo2@bar.com', password: password)
    user3 =  User.new(email: 'foo3@bar.com', password: password)
    user4 = user3
%>
<div>user1: <%= user1.encrypted_password %></div>
<div>user2: <%= user2.encrypted_password %></div>
<div>user3: <%= user3.encrypted_password %></div>
<div>user4: <%= user4.encrypted_password %></div>
<%  user3.skip_confirmation!
    user3.save!   %>
<div>user3: <%= user3.encrypted_password %></div>
<% user3.password = password %>
<div>user3: <%= user3.encrypted_password %></div>
<% user4.password = password %>
<div>user4: <%= user4.encrypted_password %></div>
```

**Result:**

line 1| user1: $2a$10$B/2jwwqdDEXhz6Sj0txLHeLpAYpDXfHdXPltuMrzdtWuDRd2gJIUi

line 2|    user2: $2a$10$ge9wb8w8CULXYMNBgzJjfeknpIBZI67lSRRod9wCjGEr4tgAjDwbG

line 3|    user3: $2a$10$6xhjZ.TRA/jpXpDUmVLhPOsAvkQUNoVS12o5K.OmjUz2i0xfntzZ.

line 4|   user4: $2a$10$6xhjZ.TRA/jpXpDUmVLhPOsAvkQUNoVS12o5K.OmjUz2i0xfntzZ.

line 5|   user3: $2a$10$6xhjZ.TRA/jpXpDUmVLhPOsAvkQUNoVS12o5K.OmjUz2i0xfntzZ.

line 6|   user3: $2a$10$U2obok44brwOGEbyHLrl6O8lNPAQ/DA14pQTLN91iv5hhC7wTZ8Aa

line 7|   user4: $2a$10$06tJre07ZFeLNhaWkWtOfOwevBdSDFa9.uRH4kBRdS5hcnMk3d.X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encrypted passwords are different because the passwords are salted by devise (bcrypt is the encryption method used by default, but any decent scheme must do the same for the sake of security).  Therefore identical passwords *should* be different in `encrypted_password` (even for the same password set repeatedly in the same object).

This shouldn't have an effect on `valid_password?` working or not, as it salts the entered password using the same salt as stored with the encrypted password, so if the underlying password is the same, this method should return true.  Something else must be going on if it's not behaving as expected.  You'd need to provide more details and/or code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: This is way late, but thanks @Tim for taking the time to explain this. Really, truly helps! As it turned out, something else in my code was causing the user to be signed out and not return as a valid object.

Comment: No problem!  Glad it helped and that you found what was causing your problem.